# Xamarin mapsforge binding generic collections issue

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin

I am trying to bind mapsforge JAR. In Overlay class of this library there are many generic collections. Overlay class implements Java.Util.IList and 
Interface Java.Util.IList want realization like this

```
"Mapsforge.Android.Maps.OverlayNs.OverlayList" does not implement "Java.Util.IList.AddAll(int, System.Collections.ICollection)" 8 23 MapForgeDroid
```

So, i created Metadata.xml Mapsforge.Android Mapsforge.Android.Maps.OverlayNs

```
  <!-- Return Java.Lang.Object in OverlayManager so that we match interface. -->
    <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.mapsforge.android.maps.overlay']/class[@name='ArrayCircleOverlay']/method[@name='createCircle']" name="managedReturn">Java.Lang.Object</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.mapsforge.android.maps.overlay']/class[@name='ArrayItemizedOverlay']/method[@name='createItem']" name="managedReturn">Java.Lang.Object</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.mapsforge.android.maps.overlay']/class[@name='ArrayWayOverlay']/method[@name='createWay']" name="managedReturn">Java.Lang.Object</attr>   

    <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.mapsforge.android.maps.overlay']/class[@name='ArrayItemizedOverlay']/method[@name='getThreadName']" name="visibility">protected</attr>
    <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.mapsforge.android.maps.overlay']/class[@name='ArrayCircleOverlay']/method[@name='getThreadName']" name="visibility">protected</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.mapsforge.android.maps.overlay']/class[@name='ArrayWayOverlay']/method[@name='getThreadName']" name="visibility">protected</attr>

  <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.mapsforge.android.maps.overlay']/class[@name='OverlayList']/method[@name='add' and count(parameter)=1]/parameter[@name='p0']" name="managedType">Java.Lang.Object</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.mapsforge.android.maps.overlay']/class[@name='OverlayList']/method[@name='add' and count(parameter)=2]/parameter[@name='p1']" name="managedType">Java.Lang.Object</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.mapsforge.android.maps.overlay']/class[@name='OverlayList']/method[@name='retainAll']/parameter[@name='p0']" name="managedType">System.Collections.ICollection</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.mapsforge.android.maps.overlay']/class[@name='OverlayList']/method[@name='removeAll']/parameter[@name='p0']" name="managedType">System.Collections.ICollection</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.mapsforge.android.maps.overlay']/class[@name='OverlayList']/method[@name='containsAll']/parameter[@name='p0']" name="managedType">System.Collections.ICollection</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.mapsforge.android.maps.overlay']/class[@name='OverlayList']/method[@name='addAll' and count(parameter)=1]/parameter[@name='p0']" name="managedType">System.Collections.ICollection</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.mapsforge.android.maps.overlay']/class[@name='OverlayList']/method[@name='addAll' and count(parameter)=2]/parameter[@name='p1']" name="managedType">System.Collections.ICollection</attr>

  <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.mapsforge.android.maps.overlay']/class[@name='OverlayList']/method[@name='set']/parameter[@name='p1']" name="managedType">Java.Lang.Object</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.mapsforge.android.maps.overlay']/class[@name='OverlayList']/method[@name='set']" name="managedReturn">Java.Lang.Object</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.mapsforge.android.maps.overlay']/class[@name='OverlayList']/method[@name='get']" name="managedReturn">Java.Lang.Object</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.mapsforge.android.maps.overlay']/class[@name='OverlayList']/method[@name='remove' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='int']]" name="managedReturn">Java.Lang.Object</attr>

  <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.mapsforge.android.maps.overlay']/class[@name='OverlayList']/method[@name='subList']" name="managedReturn">System.Collections.IList</attr>

  <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.mapsforge.android.maps.mapgenerator']/class[@name='MapGeneratorJob']/method[@name='compareTo']/parameter[@name='p0']" name="managedType">Java.Lang.Object</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.mapsforge.core']/class[@name='GeoPoint']/method[@name='compareTo']/parameter[@name='p0']" name="managedType">Java.Lang.Object</attr>
</metadata>
```

But many new erros appeared - all methods wants generic collections:

```
error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for  "Mapsforge.Android.Maps.OverlayNs.OverlayList.AddAll(int, System.Collections.ICollection)" has some invalid arguments   
error CS1503: Argument "2": cannot convert from "System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Mapsforge.Android.Maps.OverlayNs.Overlay>" to "System.Collections.ICollection"     
error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for "Mapsforge.Android.Maps.OverlayNs.OverlayList.AddAll(System.Collections.ICollection)" has some invalid arguments    
error CS1503: Argument "1": cannot convert from "System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Mapsforge.Android.Maps.OverlayNs.Overlay>" to "System.Collections.ICollection"     
error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for "Mapsforge.Android.Maps.OverlayNs.OverlayList.ContainsAll(System.Collections.ICollection)" has some invalid arguments    
error CS1503: Argument "1": cannot convert from "System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<object>" to "System.Collections.ICollection"     
error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for "Mapsforge.Android.Maps.OverlayNs.OverlayList.RemoveAll(System.Collections.ICollection)" has some invalid arguments    
error CS1503: Argument "1":  cannot convert from "System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<object>" to "System.Collections.ICollection"     
error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for "Mapsforge.Android.Maps.OverlayNs.OverlayList.RetainAll(System.Collections.ICollection)" has some invalid arguments    
error CS1503: Argument "1": cannot convert from "System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<object>" to "System.Collections.ICollection"     
error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type "System.Collections.Generic.IList<Mapsforge.Android.Maps.OverlayNs.Overlay>" to "System.Collections.IList".    
error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type "System.Collections.Generic.IList<Mapsforge.Android.Maps.OverlayNs.Overlay>" to "System.Collections.IList".
```

If i change type from System.Collections.ICollection to System.Collections.Generic.ICollection it generate "does not implement" error. What can i do to workaround this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I fell into the same problem of you during my last Xamarin android project, because I had to bind a JAR that make massive use of Java generics.

First of all you can read the following bug (https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=19740) that has been open on bugzilla, relative to the binding problem of Java generics.
In that thread there are explained the limits of the Android Callable Wrappers generator, and also the possible solution that you can implement if you need to bind a Jar that use Java generics.

In my opinion that solution is suitable only if your Jar doesn't make a massive use of generics, this means that if you only have one generic class maybe this is the best solution.

To overcome the original problem I have used another approach, because the Jar that I was binding use several generic classes that I need to call inside my Xamarin project. My approach was simply to work on the native side. This means include your Jar inside a Java Project extending the generic class with a specific type.

NOTE:
Requirements for this implementation is that you have to know the generic types that you will need.

Just to  be clear, suppose that your original Jar, called `genericJar` contains a generic class called `Event<T>`, and suppose that you know that T could be of type "A" or type "B".

What you need to do is to create a Java project that include you Jar, and then inside this project create the following classes:

- `public class EventA extends Event <A>` {...}
- `public class EventB extends Event <B>` {...}

Once you have done this you create a Jar from this java project, and use this as the starting Jar for your Xamarin Android project.
The binding project will try to bind the original `Event<T>` class, giving you the original error. To avoid this you have to work on the `Metadata.xml` inside your binding project. 
Inside `Metadata.xml` you have to add the following line to tell Xamarin to avoid binding the generic class:

```
<remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.originalJar.event']" />
```

Once you have done this you will be able to generate the DLL that you need for your Xamarin project, where you will be able to use EventA and EventB classes, avoiding generics problem.

I have found that this is the best approach at the moment to bind Java generic classes, let me know if this could help you to solve your problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution (and it works!!!)

First: remove all of the OverlayList nodes and add this:

```
<remove-node path="/api/package[@name='org.mapsforge.android.maps.overlay']/class[@name='OverlayList']" />
```

This removes the ability to directly use the OverlayList, but allows the library to work.

Comment: Hello Daniel and thank you for your solution. I found more concervative way to solve this problem, where you do not need to exclude entire OverlayList class, just couple of methods. I added this project in thread on Xamarin forum